# RecyclerView duplicates items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I looked the same topics and found nothing that could help me.
So this is my problem. I have an activity with a RecyclerView. I'm using Retrofit2 library to get list of news, here it is:

```
@GET(VERSION_V1 + "/news")
    Observable<BaseResponse<NewsListResponse>> getCompanyNews(@Query("companyId") String companyId,
                                                              @Query("query") String query,
                                                              @Query("offset") Integer offset,
                                                              @Query("limit") Integer limit,
                                                              @Query("creator") NewsCreatorType creator,
                                                              @Query("date")NewsFilterType dateFilter);
```

And I have a Presenter:

```
public void loadData(boolean refresh) {
    mCoreServices
            .getApiService()
            .getApi()
            .getCompanyNews(mCompanyId, "", 0, 100, mCompanyId == null ? NewsCreatorType.SYSTEM : NewsCreatorType.COMPANY, mFilterType)
            .map(response -> response.getResult().getItems())
            .flatMap(news -> {
                if (mCompanyId == null || "".equals(mCompanyId)) {
                    return Observable.just(news);
                } else {
                    return mCoreServices
                            .getApiService()
                            .getApi()
                            .getCompanyNews(null, "", 0, 100, NewsCreatorType.SYSTEM, mFilterType)
                            .map(response -> {
                                news.addAll(response.getResult().getItems());

                                return news;
                            });
                }
            })
            .flatMapIterable(newsItems -> newsItems)
            .map(NewsViewModel::new)
            .toSortedList((news1, news2) -> news2.getDate().compareTo(news1.getDate()))
            .retryWhen(errors -> retryAfterRefreshToken(errors))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
                if (refresh) {
                    getViewState().onShowRefresh(true);
                } else {
                    getViewState().onShowProgressBar(true);
                }

            })
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
                if (refresh) {
                    getViewState().onShowRefresh(false);
                } else {
                    getViewState().onShowProgressBar(false);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(news -> {
                mResults = news;

                getViewState().onLoadNews(mResults);
            }, new ApiExceptionObservable(TAG) {
                @Override
                public void call(String message) {
                    getViewState().onShowErrorMessage(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void unauthorized() {
                    getViewState().showUnauthorizedDialog();
                }
            });
}
```

And ofc I have a RecyclerView adapter, this is my `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder baseHolder, int position) {
    if (baseHolder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) baseHolder;

        NewsViewModel newsViewModel = mResults.get(position);

        holder.mTVTitle.setText(newsViewModel.getTitle());
        holder.mTVContent.setText(newsViewModel.getContent());

        if (NewsCreatorType.SYSTEM.equals(newsViewModel.getCreator())) {
            holder.mTVCreator.setText(newsViewModel.getCreator().getTitle());
        } else {
            holder.mTVCreator.setText(
                    holder.mTVCreator.getContext().getString(
                            newsViewModel.getCreator().getTitle(),
                            mCompanyTitle
                    )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Well, I have 2 companies doing news. News from company#1 are not duplicated, news from company#2 are always duplicated.. I don't understand where's my mistake. I checked (using debugger) the answer on my GET, it has no duplicated news, so the problem with my adapter I guess..
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I get duplicated news from Creator.SYSTEM only.

**EDIT 2.0:**
Okay, I removed `.flatMap` in my Presenter, now it works fine, but I can't understand why it was there, can someone explain please?

Comment: I'd guess, that this code `news.addAll(response.getResult().getItems());` can add the same news again (depending on your `mCompanyId`, etc.

Comment: Well, as I said, I checked what exactly I get in my Presenter with debugger. I get the list of different news..

Comment: Looks like you were right, @TmTron! I just removed ".flatMap" and now it works fine.